# sequelize.js: hasMany - belongsTo index duplication

Tags: associations, sequelize.js

Let's say I have two models — `User` and `Folder`. User may have many folders, and folder may belong only to one user — it's owner.

```
User.hasMany Folder,
  as : "Folders"
Folder.belongsTo User,
  as : "Owner"
```

As result I get index doubling in Folder model:

```
\d+ "Folders"
  Column   |           Type           |                       Modifiers                        | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id        | integer                  | not null default nextval('"Folders_id_seq"'::regclass) | plain    |              |
 createdAt | timestamp with time zone | not null                                               | plain    |              |
 updatedAt | timestamp with time zone | not null                                               | plain    |              |
 UserId    | integer                  |                                                        | plain    |              |
 OwnerId   | integer                  |                                                        | plain    |              |
```

I need this relation to be accessible from both sides:

```
user.getFolders.sucesss (folders)->
  # folders — array of user's folders
folder.getOwner.sucesss (user)->
  # user — user object
```

But instead of this I get index fields doubling. It seems fields `UserId` and `OwnerId` are created by the same association. How to avoid this?

"sequelize": "^2.0.0-rc2"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foreignKey` attribute did the trick.